# How to specify a default timeout while deploying to the build output folder?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, vstest

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx),

> you cannot avoid using a deployment folder if you are using a
>   *.testsettings file, which is required for web and load tests, coded UI tests, and any test in which you deploy an application to remote
>   machines.

I need tests to run in the build output folder because it takes a long time to copy all the dependencies, making any sort of TDD or rapid test-fix iteration impractical.

I also want tests that take too long to run to be aborted and report failure. So far the only two options I found was either to mark these tests with a TimeoutAttribute, or to use a .testsettings file. It's impractical to add and maintain same timeout in code to thousands of individual tests, and using a .testsettings is out of the question for the reason I just mentioned. Is there a way to do this while running tests in the build output folder? Alternatively, is there a third-party test framework that would support this?